# Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

now,i setup android studio 3.0 version, i updated gradle android gradle plugin.i rebuild my project.the error occured. 
the code below like this (in build.gradle):

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def oldFile = output.outputFile
        def newName = "DDD_v_" + defaultConfig.versionName
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('release')) {
            def releaseApkName = newName + '.apk'
            output.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, releaseApkName)
        }
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')) {
            def releaseApkName = newName + '_debug.apk'
            output.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, releaseApkName)
        }

    }
}
```

the error message:

> Error:(170, 1) A problem occurred configuring root project 'XXX'.
>   Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Not valid.
>   Could not get unknown property 'apkVariantData' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.
>   the focus point at the code :def oldFile = output.outputFile
>   * What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'ShouYiRen'.
>   Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Not valid.
>   Could not get unknown property 'apkVariantData' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'ShouYiRen'.
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:86)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:73)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:31)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationProjectConfigurator.runBuildOperation(BuildOperationProjectConfigurator.java:139)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationProjectConfigurator.projectBuildOperationAction(BuildOperationProjectConfigurator.java:64)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:47)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:652)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:130)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:36)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:200)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:157)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:43)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$2.execute(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:50)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:315)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:225)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:138)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:35)
  at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
  ... 78 more
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Not valid.
  at com.android.ide.common.build.ApkData.getMainOutputFile(ApkData.java:136)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl.getOutputFile(BaseVariantOutputImpl.java:60)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated.getOutputFile(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:228)
  at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:171)
  at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:55)
  at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:59)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
  at build_ail0i0d0o06lvahlcoidihlyd$_run_closure2$_closure13$_closure21.doCall(/Users/tanglang/Documents/work/projects/company/ShouYiRen/build.gradle:170)
  at build_ail0i0d0o06lvahlcoidihlyd$_run_closure2$_closure13.doCall(/Users/tanglang/Documents/work/projects/company/ShouYiRen/build.gradle:169)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
  at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
  at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
  at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
  at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:155)
  at org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet.execute(MutableActionSet.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:204)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:198)
  at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.java:63)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:128)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:621)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:610)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:539)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:535)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:89)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:78)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:221)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:145)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
  ... 85 more

BUILD FAILED in 0s

what does it mean?any suggest is thankful

Comment: any more logs than that? the ones you pasted don't seem to relate to the code you show

Comment: i past more, help me

Comment: I'm not sure, but what is line 170 of your build.gradle?

Comment: yeah,i am sure.i doubt it gradle plugin version.but i cant find it out